# MacOS/Bash - Replace filename with parent directory name

Tags: bash, macos, rename

I have about 600 folders with one file each. The structure is as follow:

Folder: 123 Title of a file

File: Title of a file

So the filename and folder name are identical except for the number. I would like to add the number to the filename or just replace the whole filename with the folder name. I have put the following together, but I do not find a way to add the file extension.

```
for file in */*.txt; do echo mv -- "$file" "${file%/*}/${file%/*}"; done
```

I added it at the end "file/*.txt", but somehow it does not work.

Would appreciate some guidance - thanks!

Comment: Aside from the correct answer given by Barmar: If you have a set of directories, each containing just a single file, AND this file is supposed to have the same name as the directory, wouldn't it be a simpler layout to get rid of the directories and just store the files instead of the directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory name doesn't have the `.txt` extension name. You need to add that back when renaming the file.

```
for file in */*.txt; do 
    dir="${file%/*}"
    echo mv -- "$file" "$dir/$dir.txt"
done
```

Comment: duh - I tried something similar, but did not work. Thanks so much

Comment: The logic becomes more obvious when you split out the `$dir` variable. And the code becomes easier to read.